# ggplot python: How to insert "counts" in line plots that represents each point

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, python-ggplot

I'm trying to visualize counts of each category across years. My dataframe is as below:

```
STATE    YEAR     COUNT
IN       2012        0
CA       2013       35
TX       2014       32
```

I used ggplot to have a simple line graph

```
ggplot(aes(x='YEAR', y='COUNT'), data=IN)  + geom_line() + geom_point(color = "red")+ ggtitle("RECORDS")
```

[image]

Is there a way to display the "counts" (0,35,32) at each red point in the graph?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

ax = df.plot(x='YEAR',y='COUNT', c='black', lw=1.2)
df.plot.scatter(x='YEAR',y='COUNT', c='r', s=30, ax=ax)
df.apply(lambda x: ax.text(x['YEAR'], x['COUNT']+2, x['COUNT']), axis=1)
```

Result:

[image]

Data:

```
In [200]: df
Out[200]:
  STATE  YEAR  COUNT
0    IN  2012      0
1    CA  2013     35
2    TX  2014     32
3    IN  2015     37
4    CA  2016     63
5    TX  2017     81
```

Comment: I do see the counts now, but the point '0' and '81' gets cut in half in the plot. I tried to resize the image, but it did not help

Comment: @sagar, i don't think it's easy to prevent it and make it generic at the same time...

Comment: But your plot displays it perfectly.(the example which you used)

Comment: @sagar, what is your Pandas version? I'm using Pandas 0.22.0

Comment: when I tried to plot other columns in the dataframe with your code, I got the following error. `ValueError: Image size of 418x142840 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.`

Comment: Pandas version - 0.20.1

Answer (score 0):

Using plotnine

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
from plotnine import *

sio = StringIO("""
  STATE  YEAR  COUNT
0    IN  2012      0
1    CA  2013     35
2    TX  2014     32
3    IN  2015     37
4    CA  2016     63
5    TX  2017     81
""")

df = pd.read_csv(sio, sep='\s+')

(ggplot(aes(x='YEAR', y='COUNT'), data=df)
 + geom_line()
 + geom_point(color='red')
 + geom_text(aes(label='COUNT'), nudge_y=3, size=10)
 + labs(title='RECORDS')
)
```

[image]